# Ajax File Upload unusal behaviour when using sessions

Tags: ajax, vb.net, session, file-upload, icallbackeventhandler

I have just implemented an Ajax File Upload control that uses a progress bar. I am a little confused. When i use the control on pages that dont use sessions, the progress bar with no problems will show the user the actual progress of the file being uploaded from 0%,1%,2%,3%.......% to 100%. Now when i move this control onto a web page that uses a session, this session stores the user information such as screenname, email, etc... the file uploads with no problems but **the problem is that the progress bar does allow the user to see the progress until the file is finised uploading and the progress bar jumps straight from 0% to 100% uploaded** and doenst really show the full progress of the file whilst being uploaded.

Why is this behaviour occuring when i use sessions? where the progress of the file being uploaded isn't being shown to the user until the file uploads.

i would be grateful for your feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to allow the progress bar to work is to use a httpmodule for the progress bar to update while the file is being processed serverside.